# Make reusable iterable out of generator

Tags: python, generator, python-decorators, iterable

I want to convert generators to reusable iterables. For example, consider generator:

```
def myrange(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i
```

It generates one-use iterator:

```
x = myrange(3)
print(list(x)) # [0, 1, 2]
print(list(x)) # []
```

I want to add a decorator to the definition of `myrange` such that it produces reusable iterable (like the usual `range`) instead of one-use iterator:

```
x = myrange(3)
print(list(x)) # [0, 1, 2]
print(list(x)) # [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: "Iterators are required to have an __iter__() method that returns the iterator object itself so every **iterator is also iterable**" [(Python docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) - You might want to be more specific.

Comment: @matszwecja, yeah, you are right, updated question. (Are there any technical term for "reusable iterables"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def mk_reusable(f):
    """
    Makes a reusable iterable out of generator by remembering its arguments
    """

    class MyIterable:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self._args = args
            self._kwargs = kwargs

        def __iter__(self):
            yield from f(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

    return MyIterable


# TEST
@mk_reusable
def myrange(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i

x = myrange(3)
assert list(x) == [0, 1, 2]
assert list(x) == [0, 1, 2]
# can consume it twice
```